# SetSite failed for package Error when Loading Sitecore Rocks Package using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, sitecore-rocks

When loading a project in Visual Studio 2019 the Sitecore Rocks refuses to load properly.  The error information is listed below.

```
<description>SetSite failed for package [SitecorePackage]Source: &apos;&apos; 
Description: Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))&#x000D;&#x000A;
System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 
(E_NOTIMPL))&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at EnvDTE.Project.get_FileName()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Projects.ProjectManager.LoadProjects()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Shell.Pipelines.Initialization.LoadSolution.Process(InitializationPipeline pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.ProcessInternal(T pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Continue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.ProcessInternal(T pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Continue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.ProcessInternal(T pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Continue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.ProcessInternal(T pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Continue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.ProcessInternal(T pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Continue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.ProcessInternal(T pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Continue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.ProcessInternal(T pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Continue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.ProcessInternal(T pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Continue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.ProcessInternal(T pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Continue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.ProcessInternal(T pipeline)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Continue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Extensibility.Pipelines.Pipeline`1.Start()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.Shell.Environment.ShellHost.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Sitecore.Rocks.SitecorePackage.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__56.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- 
End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass16_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- 
End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;--- 
End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()</description>
```

Comment: DId you try this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/how-can-i-fix-the-microsoft-visual-studio-error-package-did-not-load-correctly

Comment: Yes I did, It was the first solution I tried before posting this submission.  It allowed me to load the solution without any issues but as soon as I attempted to use Sitecore Rocks in VS 2019 I got the the same package failed to load error.  I believe the underlying error is related to 'SetSite failed for package' as identified in the stack trace above.  I found no help so far for how to resolve that one.

Comment: Hey Joseph, have you been able to solve the error?
I'm have the same exception on my environment. Not sure why too. I have tried the mentioned solution by @GauravAgarwal too and it doesn't work for me either